# Capybara form with multiple: true getting sent the wrong value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, capybara

I'm using capybara 2.1.0 and have a form with `multiple: true` (allowing me to upload multiple files).  The site works fine in browsers, but capybara has a problem in that the field is being submitted with the content `""` instead of `nil` when I leave that field blank.  I'm then getting an error from Paperclip about `""` being an invalid file name (makes sense, there is no file named `""`).

Here's the form:

```
= simple_form_for([@site, @zone], mulitpart: true) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :site_id
    = f.input :default_state

    = file_field_tag "zone_shapefiles_asset", multiple: true, name: "zone[shapefiles_attributes][][asset]"
    = label_tag "X"
    = text_field_tag 'x_coords[]', nil, id: "x_coords_1"

    = label_tag "Y"
    = text_field_tag 'y_coords[]', nil, id: "y_coords_1"

    = label_tag "X"
    = text_field_tag 'x_coords[]', nil, id: "x_coords_2"

    = label_tag "Y"
    = text_field_tag 'y_coords[]', nil, id: "y_coords_2"

    = label_tag "X"
    = text_field_tag 'x_coords[]', nil, id: "x_coords_3"

    = label_tag "Y"
    = text_field_tag 'y_coords[]', nil, id: "y_coords_3"

    = label_tag "X"
    = text_field_tag 'x_coords[]', nil, id: "x_coords_4"

    = label_tag "Y"
    = text_field_tag 'y_coords[]', nil, id: "y_coords_4"

    = link_to "Add Point", "#", id: "add_point", data: { fields: label_tags.gsub("\"", "'") }

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

And the error:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError: No handler found for ""
./spec/features/zones_spec.rb:50:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

From this spec:

```
it "can create region for zone" do
    fill_in "x_coords_1", with: 0
    fill_in "y_coords_1", with: 0
    fill_in "x_coords_2", with: 10
    fill_in "y_coords_2", with: 0
    fill_in "x_coords_3", with: 10
    fill_in "y_coords_3", with: 10
    fill_in "x_coords_4", with: 0
    fill_in "y_coords_4", with: 10
    click_button "Create Zone"
    page.should have_content "Zone was successfully created
end
```

running rails 3.2.13

capybara 2.1.0

default rack_test driver

Comment: What version of Capybara are you using, and which driver?

Comment: Updated the question.  Capybara 2.1.0, default rack_test driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in my form.

I have `mulitpart: true` instead of `multipart: true`.  Notice the misspelling of multipart.